# Throwing an instance of "out of range" in c++

Tags: c++

When i build and run the code, i get the next error: "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'

```
what<>: vector::_M_range_check: __n <which is 0> >= this->size<> <which is 0>
```

I don't know how to fix this problem, I am new to coding!
What I'm trying to do is using a collection (list) of integers and allowing the user to select options from a menu to perform operations on the list.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector <int>numbers{};
    int nr_to_add{};
    char selection{};
    double average{};
    int min = numbers.at(0);
    int max = numbers.at(0);

    do{
        cout << "P - Print numbers!" << endl;
        cout << "A - Add numbers!" << endl;
        cout << "M - Display mean of the numbers!" << endl;
        cout << "S - Display the smallest number!" << endl;
        cout << "L - Display the largest number!" << endl;
        cout << "Q - Quit" << endl;
        cout << "Enter your selection: ";
        cin >> selection;

        if(selection == 'p' || selection == 'P'){
                for(int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++)
                    cout << "The numbers are: " << numbers[i];
            if(numbers.empty())
                cout << "[] - the list is empty! " << "\nYou should add some numbers!" << endl;
                cout << "Add some numbers: ";
                cin >> nr_to_add;
                numbers.push_back(nr_to_add);
        }else if(selection == 'a' || selection == 'A'){
            cout << "Add the number you want: ";
            cin >> nr_to_add;
            cout << "\n" << nr_to_add << " has been added successfully!" << endl;
            numbers.push_back(nr_to_add);
        }else if(selection == 'm' || selection == 'M'){
                if(numbers.empty())
                    cout << "Unable to calculate de average - no data introduced!" << endl;
                if(numbers.size() != 0)
                    average = accumulate(numbers.begin(),numbers.end(), 0.0)/numbers.size();
                    cout << "The average is: " << average << endl;

        }else if(selection == 's' || selection == 'S'){
            if(numbers.empty())
                cout << "Unable to determine the smallest number - list is empty!";
            if(numbers.size() != 0)
                for(int i = 0,n = 0; i <= n; i++){
                    if(numbers.at(i) < min)
                        min = numbers[i];
                        cout << "The smallest number is: " << min << endl;
                }

        }else if(selection == 'l' || selection == 'L'){
            if(numbers.empty())
                cout << "Unable to determine the largest number - list is empty!";
            if(numbers.size() != 0)
                for(int i = 0,n = 0; i <= n; i++){
                    if(numbers.at(i) > max)
                        max = numbers[i];
                        cout << "The largest number is: " << max << endl;
            }
        }else if(selection == 'q' || selection == 'Q'){
            cout << "Goodbye..." << endl;
        } else {
            cout << "Unknown selection, please try again" << endl;
        }

    } while(selection != 'q' && selection != 'Q');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int min = numbers.at(0);` There is no number at index 0, your vector is empty.

Comment: *"terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range' what<>: vector::_M_range_check: __n >= this->size<>* -- Your vector is too small -- that in a nutshell is what that error is telling you.

Comment: You only need very little code to reproduce the error: `#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> numbers;
    int min = numbers.at(0);
}`

Comment: `int i = 0,n = 0; i <= n; i++` won't do a whole lot. Your loop will only execute once. Not that that is this problem, though.

Comment: This is an annoying "feature" of C++ which goes against common sense and against the recommendations at isocpp.org ("What shouldn't I use exceptions for?"). Actually, your program should just die in an assertion, but you are given an exception. Which _suggests_ that there is a kind of runtime error which happens _exceptionally_, and which you can presumably somehow handle, when in reality that's not the case (in reality, program logic is bad, and the failure occurs every time, not exceptionally). Not sure why it was done that way, but meh, it is what it is. Just learn not to do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are calling `at(0)` on an empty `vector`.  That is what the `out_of_range` error is telling you.  You need to move the calls into your `if` statements where the values are actually being used, after you perform your `empty()` checks.

Also, your `min` and `max` loops are coded wrong.  And you don't need to use loops at all, you can use the standard [`std::min_element()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element) and [`std::max_element()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) algorithms instead (you are already using the `std::accumulate()` algorithm).

Try something more like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> numbers{};
    int nr_to_add;
    char selection;
    double average_nr;
    int min_nr, max_nr;

    do {
        cout << "P - Print numbers!" << endl;
        cout << "A - Add numbers!" << endl;
        cout << "M - Display mean of the numbers!" << endl;
        cout << "S - Display the smallest number!" << endl;
        cout << "L - Display the largest number!" << endl;
        cout << "Q - Quit" << endl;
        cout << "Enter your selection: ";

        if (!(cin >> selection)) {
            selection = '\0';
            cin.clear();
        }
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

        if (selection == 'p' || selection == 'P') {
            if (numbers.empty()) {
                cout << "The list is empty! " << "\nYou should add some numbers!" << endl;
            } else {
                cout << "The numbers are:" 
                for(size_t i = 0; i < numbers.size(); ++i) {
                    cout << " " << numbers[i];
                }
                cout << endl; 
            }
        }
        else if (selection == 'a' || selection == 'A') {
            cout << "Add the number you want: ";
            if (cin >> nr_to_add) {
                numbers.push_back(nr_to_add);
                cout << "\n" << nr_to_add << " has been added successfully!" << endl;
            } else {
                cout << "Bad input, please try again" << endl;
                cin.clear();
            }
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }
        else if (selection == 'm' || selection == 'M'){
            if (numbers.empty()) {
                cout << "Unable to calculate the average - list is empty!" << endl;
            } else {
                average_nr = accumulate(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), 0.0) / numbers.size();
                cout << "The average is: " << average_nr << endl;
            }
        }
        else if (selection == 's' || selection == 'S') {
            if (numbers.empty()) {
                cout << "Unable to determine the smallest number - list is empty!";
            } else {
                /*
                min_nr = numbers[0];
                for(size_t i = 1; i < numbers.size(); ++i){
                    if (numbers[i] < min_nr) {
                        min_nr = numbers[i];
                    }
                }
                */
                min_nr = *min_element(numbers.begin(), numbers.end());
                cout << "The smallest number is: " << min_nr << endl;
            }
        }
        else if (selection == 'l' || selection == 'L') {
            if (numbers.empty()) {
                cout << "Unable to determine the largest number - list is empty!";
            } else {
                /*
                max_nr = numbers[0];
                for(size_t i = 1; i < numbers.size(); ++i){
                    if (numbers[i] > max_nr) {
                        max_nr = numbers[i];
                    }
                }
                */
                max_nr = *max_element(numbers.begin(), numbers.end());
                cout << "The largest number is: " << max_nr << endl;
            }
        }
        else if (selection == 'q' || selection == 'Q') {
            cout << "Goodbye..." << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Unknown selection, please try again" << endl;
        }
    }
    while (selection != 'q' && selection != 'Q');

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector <int>numbers{};
    int nr_to_add{};
    char selection{};
    double average{};
    int min = 0;
    int max = 0;

    do {
        cout << "P - Print numbers!" << endl;
        cout << "A - Add numbers!" << endl;
        cout << "M - Display mean of the numbers!" << endl;
        cout << "S - Display the smallest number!" << endl;
        cout << "L - Display the largest number!" << endl;
        cout << "Q - Quit" << endl;
        cout << "Enter your selection: ";
        cin >> selection;

        if (selection == 'p' || selection == 'P') {
            for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++)
                cout << "The numbers are: " << numbers[i];
            if (numbers.empty()) {
                cout << "[] - the list is empty! " << "\nYou should add some numbers!" << endl;
                cout << "Add some numbers: ";
                cin >> nr_to_add;
                numbers.push_back(nr_to_add);
                min = nr_to_add;
                max = nr_to_add;
            }
        }
        else if (selection == 'a' || selection == 'A') {
            cout << "Add the number you want: ";
            cin >> nr_to_add;
            cout << "\n" << nr_to_add << " has been added successfully!" << endl;
            if (numbers.empty) {
                min = nr_to_add;
                max = nr_to_add;
            }
            else {
                if (min > nr_to_add) min = nr_to_add;
                if (max < nr_to_add) max = nr_to_add;
            }

            numbers.push_back(nr_to_add);
        }
        else if (selection == 'm' || selection == 'M') {
            if (numbers.empty())
                cout << "Unable to calculate de average - no data introduced!" << endl;
            if (numbers.size() != 0)
                average = accumulate(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), 0.0) / numbers.size();
            cout << "The average is: " << average << endl;

        }
        else if (selection == 's' || selection == 'S') {
            if (numbers.empty())
                cout << "Unable to determine the smallest number - list is empty!";
            else
                cout << "The smallest number is: " << min << endl;

        }
        else if (selection == 'l' || selection == 'L') {
            if (numbers.empty())
                cout << "Unable to determine the largest number - list is empty!";
            else
                cout << "The largest number is: " << max << endl;
        }
        else if (selection == 'q' || selection == 'Q') {
            cout << "Goodbye..." << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Unknown selection, please try again" << endl;
        }

    } while (selection != 'q' && selection != 'Q');
    return 0;
```